# zoom plugin requires older version of jquery but it's conflicting with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a zoom plugin requires old version of jquery and in the main time i am using Twitter Bootstrap which requires newer version of jquery library, however the Twitter Bootstrap is working but the zoom plugin is not working - down below the js order

```
 <!-- The JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var bt = jQuery.noConflict(true);

bt(function() {
 bt('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bt(this).tab('show');
    });
});

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

var zoom_1_6 = $.noConflict(true);

   zoom_1_6(function() {

    zoom_1_6('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
        zoomType: 'standard',
        lens:true,
        preloadImages: false,
        alwaysOn:false
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.

```
<!-- primary first --->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- secondary second --->
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(function() {

    $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
        zoomType: 'standard',
        lens:true,
        preloadImages: false,
        alwaysOn:false
    });

    // revert ownership of $ and jQuery to 1.10.2
    $.noConflict(true);    

    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

});

</script>
```

the order of the script includes are VERY important. Include scripts that require 1.10.2 immediately after 1.10.2, and scripts that require 1.6 immediately after 1.6.

Comment: so, it always has to be like 
newer version follows by older version

Comment: Not always, you could do it in the opposite direction, but it makes more sense(to me at least) to do newer version first so that when you do $.noConflict, everything will look at new version rather than old version.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care about IE7 and older (I don't) Just delete following lines where if statemests about explorer 7 or older in "jquery.jqzoom-core.js"

23

```
var isIE6 = ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7);
```

460

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 7) {
                $(this.node).empty().append(this.image);
            }
```

598

```
 if (isIE6 && settings.zoomType != 'innerzoom') {
                    this.ieframe.width = this.node.width();
                    this.ieframe.height = this.node.height();
                    this.ieframe.left = this.node.leftpos;
                    this.ieframe.top = this.node.toppos;
                    this.ieframe.css({
                        display: 'block',
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: this.ieframe.left,
                        top: this.ieframe.top,
                        zIndex: 99,
                        width: this.ieframe.width + 'px',
                        height: this.ieframe.height + 'px'
                    });
                    $('.zoomPad', el).append(this.ieframe);
                    this.ieframe.show();
                };
```